# Query text specifies use_legacy_sql:false, while API options specify:true

Tags: r, google-bigquery, bigrquery

I'm using standardSQL with bigrquery:

```
library(bigrquery)
project <- "</project-name>"


sql <- "
#standardSQL
SELECT
</sql-query>;"


result <- query_exec(sql, project = project, useLegacySql = FALSE)
```

When I run the R script I get the following error:

```
 "Error: Query text specifies use_legacy_sql:false, while API options specify:true"
```

Any ideas what might be going on here?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's `use_legacy_sql = FALSE` (note the underscores, not camelcase)

See [here](https://github.com/rstats-db/bigrquery/blob/08b79afcb9675bacd0277c61b81209bbdb76879e/R/job-query.R#L36).

Answer (score -1):

You just need to uncheck of "use legacy sql" at the  "hide options".
Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It is an API question, not a UI question