# UseLegacySql=FALSE ignored, BigRQuery

Tags: r, google-bigquery, bigrquery

I am having some issues with BigRQuery not recognizing the `useLegacySql=false` argument in my `query_exec()` function.

My call looks like `query_exec(query, project = project, useLegacySql = FALSE, max_pages = Inf)`

I have a few issues:

1) When attempting a workaround by passing "#standardSQL..." in the query I get the error

> Error: 1.979 - 1.979: No query found

2) When I pass `useLegacySql = false` I get:

> Error: 1.1 - 1.966: Unrecognized token UNION. [Try using standard SQL....]

3) I have also tried this with `use_Legacy_Sql = false` with the same error:

> Error: 1.1 - 1.966: Unrecognized token UNION. [Try using standard SQL....]

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

As presented in your question you still didn't use the input:

```
query_exec(query,
           project,
           ...,
           use_legacy_sql = FALSE)
```

You used `use_Legacy_Sql` instead of `use_legacy_sql`, I wonder if this is making a difference.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, to my knowledge the input is complete. I edited the main comment to include it. Thanks

Comment: what I tried to suggest here is trying the input `use_legacy_sql` in lower case as it's expected by the function contract.

Comment: Using the lower case worked!! Thank you so much. I owe you some beers!

Comment: Isn't this a dupicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46275367/query-text-specifies-use-legacy-sqlfalse-while-api-options-specifytrue?